# Is it possible to import a file in a proof only in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm looking for something like this

Suppose I have a lemma that is using some long named module

```
Lemma foo : SomeLongNamedModule.foo = blablabla.
```

I want to import `SomeLongNamedModule` inside the proof but left scope outside of the proof clean. I'm looking for something like this

```
Lemma foo : SomeLongNamedModule.foo = blablabla
  Local Import SomeLongNamedModule
  ...

Qed

(* Here SomeLongNamedModule is not polluting the scope *)
```

Is that possible? I think about wrapping it in a module but it seems overkill to me. To explain my use case, I'm working on a code base where we avoid `Import`, but during the
writing of proofs I insert the `Import` and then remove it later and refactor the proof.
If there is something `Local Import` it would be possible left it there in some cases.

One option is using modules, this works

```
Module Bar.
  Parameter bar : forall {A : Type}, A -> A.
End Bar.

Module Foo.
  Import Bar.

  Check bar.
End Foo.

Fail Check bar. (* bar not defined here *)
```

My guess is that Lemma is not a scope so I can't do this.

Comment: Have you tried putting your proof inside a `Section` ? You'll get a warning "require-in-section, fragile` though

Comment: No, in that same project we don't use sections only modules.

Comment: Why not just put the proof inside a module?

Comment: That's my current solution, I want to know if there is a better alternative